How to make an unpaid version of the new notebook assistant?
I already pay many dollars to openai and other llm vendors every month and I have a separate key for each service. Is there a way to make a side-docked "Assistant Notebook"
that does the same thing as this but for free?
https://www.wolfram.com/notebook-assistant-llm-kit/


This doesn't seem like an on-topic question.

Why cannot you just use Chat Notebook with your services?
Also see alot of different approaches here: https://wolfr.am/AIgroup

This is definitely on-topic, AI-assisted workflows are the most important topic today. Shouldn't be too hard, all that side notebook is doing is restricting the context to a given notebook...

I'd certainly be interested in the results of (someone else) doing some spelunking in the 400 MB of downloaded data associated with this. Presumably one could query theSemanticSearchIndex oneself using SemanticSearch and then send the associated content and some prompts to the LLM of your choice to achieve parts of the functionality.
